# How to check Day format in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to check whether current day is equal or not in laravel as follow.

```
$sales = DB::table('c_sales_detail')
 ->where('c_sales_detail.package_id',"=",'$package->code')
 ->where(DATE_FORMAT('c_sales_detail.created_at', '%W'), "=", "Wednesday")
 ->count();
```

But got following error. Please help me to solve that problem.

> Error::date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

Answer (score 1):

```
->where(DATE_FORMAT('c_sales_detail.created_at', '%W'), "=", "Wednesday")
```

Are you trying to call the PHP function `date_format` here, or the MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT` …?

Right now you are calling the PHP function. If you want to call the MySQL function, then it would have to be part of the string you pass to `where()`, not *around* the string value. And `c_sales_detail.created_at` should be a column name then – right now, it is just a string value.

I guess this is what you actually want:

```
->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(c_sales_detail.created_at, '%W') = 'Wednesday'")
```

*Edit: Replaced `->where()` with `->whereRaw()`, according to Joel’s comment.*

Comment: And since it's a MySQL function, it needs to be wrapped in a DB::raw() or whereRaw() call.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks, I am not familiar with the specifics of Laravel’s database layer. I edited my answer, is that the correct way of using `whereRaw` here? (Documentation suggests that the comparison operator is not a separate argument in this case, correct?)

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure but it looks pretty good to me. Have an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure but try this code,
Replace,

```
->where(DATE_FORMAT('c_sales_detail.created_at', '%W'), "=", "Wednesday")
```

With,

```
->where(DATE_FORMAT(strtotime('c_sales_detail.created_at'), '%W'), "=", "Wednesday")
```

Comment: got that error.  
ErrorException
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

You also try this code --

```
$query = DB::table('c_sales_detail');
$query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%W') = 'Tuesday'");
$result = $query->get();
```